# Can Wildfly/JBoss Management CLI with embedded host controller use a temporary local domain controller?

Tags: command-line-interface, jboss, wildfly

I need to use Wildfly/JBoss Management CLI to set up managed servers connections to the domain controller. It's under automation, so I'm using the [Embedded Host Controller](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/pt-br/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/management_cli_guide/index#running_embedded_server) to avoid the hassle of answering prompts for the connection credentials or the vulnerability of passing them in the command line.

Obviously, in this connection, the domain controller connection isn't configured yet, so I get trapped in a chicken-and-egg situation. I can workaround it by passing all setting in the command line, but in this unsafe way:

```
/opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh -Djboss.domain.master.address=<IP> --user=<User>- --password=<Password>
```

Is there any way to "simulate" a "local" domain controller, just for the embedded host controller to work, and I use it to safely set connection stuff?